# Wordpress support

Tags: wordpress

I like to get a customer website to full cms website / blog / magazine / ecommerce

I will go with wordpress (joomla and drupal on the runner up list)

I will for sure need support for customizing template, code, php and plugins

I always found AMAZING support from stackoverflow, i like to have the same thing for wp... do you know where i should ask my Wordpress question and post my code...?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://wordpress.org/support/